# How to insert value into FK column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Just a heads up, I'm quite new to this but I'd be really thankful if you can drop some knowledge.

I have SQL tables:

1. Table 'companies' which has the 'company_id' column as primary key.
2. Table 'users' which has the 'company_id' column as foreign key, referencing the 'companies' table, of course.

Upon signup, two types of users are created.

1. A manager - who also creates a company
2. A regular user - who joins the company

I want the regular user to have the company_id of the company he registered to. The user decides to which company he enrolls using a unique company_code.

The code looks like this, so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT company_id FROM companies WHERE company_code='$company_code';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$result=$row["company_id"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, user_uid, user_pwd, role, company_id) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd', '$role', '$result');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../signup.php?singup=success");
exit();
```

Everything seems to work just fine, but not the company_id column which is always NULL. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I've already though about assigning the values of the last created user_id and the company_id that matches the company_code to variables and run a query similar to this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `company_id` = '$company_id' WHERE `users`.`user_id` = $user_id;
```

but it really feels like over complicating my existence.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 2):

You named your variable `$result` on line `4`.

```
$result=$row["company_id"];
```

It should be:

```
$real_id = $row["company_id"];
```

Comment: You are right. I tried different solutions so I must've forgot it like that. Unfortunately, it still doesn't change the result, but thank you.

Comment: @LemnaruEduard-Mihai Have you tried doing a `var_dump($real_id);` to see if you have the right value for the company's id?